# Intellij IDEA Community edition and Ruby plugin

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA Community Edition and I wanted to install the Ruby plugin, but it is only available for the full version of the IDEA, although distributed free license. How to install it in community edition version?

Comment: are you a university student?

Comment: You can get ultimate edition for free: https://www.jetbrains.com/student/

Answer (score 3):

You answered your question already: you cannot use Ruby in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, the plugin won't work:

> Supported only in **Ultimate Edition**: ... Ruby, JRuby ...

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

As stated in a comment, you can get IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for free (non-commercial use only) as a [student](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/).